# Sending data from calculator form to other page form in Laravel and JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-6

I apologize in advance for my English but I am a Slovak and I also helped a bit with Google Translator :)

I hope to find help here for my problem ...

I have a loan calculator examples will be given below.

I try to make sure that when I have a calculator on the **domain.xx/loan** page, I need to achieve that when I choose the loan amount, loan maturity and when I click the button I want the page to redirect to **domain.xx/request** ... where the form will be ready

The problem is that I don't know how to send the information from the calculator to the second page so that it is attached to the form that will be filled in and it will be sent to the DB

I hope you understand my problem.

**I use: Laravel and JS**

```js
$("document").ready(function() {

const rangeSliderAmount   = document.querySelector('.lc-range-slider-amount');
const rangeSliderMonth    = document.querySelector('.lc-range-slider-month');
const rangeValueBarAmount = document.querySelector('#lc-range-value-bar-amount');
const rangeValueBarMonth  = document.querySelector('#lc-range-value-bar-month');
const rangeValueAmount    = document.querySelector('#lc-range-value-amount');
const rangeValueMonth     = document.querySelector('#lc-range-value-month');
const rangeAmount         = document.getElementById("lc-amount");
const rangeMonth          = document.getElementById("lc-month");

let isDown = false;

function dragHandler() {
  isDown = !isDown;
  if (!isDown) {
    rangeValueAmount.style.setProperty('opacity', '0');
    rangeValueMonth.style.setProperty('opacity', '0');
  } else {
    rangeValueAmount.style.setProperty('opacity', '0');
    rangeValueMonth.style.setProperty('opacity', '0');
  }
}

function dragOn(e) {
  if (!isDown) return;
  rangeValueHandler();
}

function rangeValueHandler() {
  amountPercentage            = `${((rangeSliderAmount.value - 500) * 100) / (6000 - 500)}%`;
  monthPercentage             = `${((rangeSliderMonth.value - 6) * 100) / (60 - 6)}%`;
  rangeValueBarAmount.style.setProperty('width', amountPercentage);
  rangeValueBarMonth.style.setProperty('width', monthPercentage);
  rangeValueAmount.innerHTML  = `${rangeSliderAmount.value}`;
  rangeValueMonth.innerHTML   = `${rangeSliderMonth.value}`;
  rangeAmount.innerHTML       = `${rangeSliderAmount.value}`;
  rangeMonth.innerHTML        = `${rangeSliderMonth.value}`;
  vypocetSplatka();
}

rangeValueHandler();
rangeSliderAmount.addEventListener('mousedown', dragHandler);
rangeSliderAmount.addEventListener('mousemove', dragOn);
rangeSliderAmount.addEventListener('mouseup', dragHandler);
rangeSliderAmount.addEventListener('click', rangeValueHandler);
rangeSliderAmount.addEventListener('touchstart', dragHandler);
rangeSliderAmount.addEventListener('touchmove', dragOn);
rangeSliderAmount.addEventListener('touchend', dragHandler);
rangeSliderAmount.addEventListener('touchstart', rangeValueHandler);

rangeSliderMonth.addEventListener('mousedown', dragHandler);
rangeSliderMonth.addEventListener('mousemove', dragOn);
rangeSliderMonth.addEventListener('mouseup', dragHandler);
rangeSliderMonth.addEventListener('click', rangeValueHandler);
rangeSliderMonth.addEventListener('touchstart', dragHandler);
rangeSliderMonth.addEventListener('touchmove', dragOn);
rangeSliderMonth.addEventListener('touchend', dragHandler);
rangeSliderMonth.addEventListener('touchstart', rangeValueHandler);


function slideValue(inputElement) {
    var sliderElement = inputElement.closest('.lc-ranger-box').find('.slider');
    var val = parseInt(inputElement.val().replace(' ', '')) || 0;
    var sliderMax = $(sliderElement).slider('option', 'max');
    var sliderMin = $(sliderElement).slider('option', 'min');

    if (val > sliderMax) {
        val = sliderMax;
    }
    if (val < sliderMin) {
        val = sliderMin;
    }
    $(sliderElement).slider('value', val);

    val = formatNumber(val, 0, ',', ' ');
    if (inputElement.val() !== val) {
      inputElement.val(val);
    }
  }

  $('.slider-value .value').change(function(){
    slideValue($(this));
    vypocetSplatka();
  });

  vypocetSplatka();

  $('.insurance-box').on('change', 'input[name=poistenie]', function(){
    vypocetSplatka();
  });

  function formatNumber(number, decimals, dec_point, thousands_sep) {
    var str = number.toFixed(decimals ? decimals : 0).toString().split('.');
    var parts = [];
    for (var i = str[0].length; i > 0; i -= 3) {
      parts.unshift(str[0].substring(Math.max(0, i - 3), i));
    }
    str[0] = parts.join(thousands_sep ? thousands_sep : ',');
    return str.join(dec_point ? dec_point : '.');
  }

  function vypocetSplatka() {
    var mesiace = parseInt($('[data-value="months"]').html());
    var pozicka = parseInt($('[data-value="loan"]').html().replace(' ', ''));
    var poplatok = (pozicka / 100) * 2;
    $('.hascharge').show();
    if(pozicka <= -1){
        poplatok = 0;
        $('.hascharge').hide();
    }
    var benefit = 2;
    var perc, payment_mpr, payment_mpr_full, insurance, payment_month, payment_month_full, suma, suma_full, rateValue, rpmn;
    $('[data-value="charge"]').text(poplatok);
    $('[data-value="months-val"]').text(mesiace);
    $('span[data-value="loan"]').text(price_format(pozicka));
    if (pozicka <= 300) {
      perc = 15.18;
    } else if (pozicka <= 700) {
      perc = 13.9;
    } else if (pozicka <= 1499) {
      perc = 11.4;
    } else {
      perc = 8.9;
    }
    if (pozicka <= 300 && mesiace<=60 && mesiace>=6) {
      perc = 15.18;
    } else if (pozicka <= 679 && mesiace<=60 && mesiace>=6) {
      perc = 13.9;
    } else if (pozicka <= 720 && mesiace<=60 && mesiace>=6) {
      perc = 10.01;
    } else if (pozicka <= 1499 && mesiace<=60 && mesiace>=6) {
      perc = 11.4;
    } else if (mesiace<=60 && mesiace>=6) {
      perc = 8.9;
    }

    var diff = (Math.round((perc - benefit) * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
    diff = diff.replace('.', ',');
    $('[data-value="interest"]').text(diff);

    var pmt_ir_full = perc / 1200;
    var pmt_ir = (perc - benefit) / 1200;

    //pmt_ir = 13.9 / 1200;
    var pmt_np = mesiace;
    var pmt_pv = -pozicka;

    if (pmt_np > 0 && pmt_pv < 0) {
      payment_mpr = pmt(pmt_ir, pmt_np, pmt_pv);
      payment_mpr_full = pmt(pmt_ir_full, pmt_np, pmt_pv);

      $('.insurance-label').text('');
      // poistenie
      insurance = 0;

      if ($('input[name=poistenie]:checked').val() === '1') {
        insurance += 0.081 * pozicka / 100;
        $('.insurance-label').text('vrÄ‚Ë‡tane poistenia');
      }
      if ($('input[name=poistenie]:checked').val() === '2') {
        insurance += 0.148 * pozicka / 100;
        $('.insurance-label').text('vrÄ‚Ë‡tane poistenia');
      }
      //payment_mpr += ' Ă˘â€šÂ¬';
      payment_month = rd(payment_mpr + insurance);
      payment_month_full = rd(payment_mpr_full + insurance);
      payment_mpr = rd(payment_mpr);

      suma = payment_month * mesiace + poplatok;
      suma_full = payment_month_full * mesiace + poplatok;

      $('#clientsave').html(price_format(suma_full - suma) + ' &euro;');

    } else {
      payment_mpr = '';
    }
    $('[data-value="fee"]').html(price_format(payment_month));
    $('[data-value="fee-val"]').text(price_format(payment_mpr));

    rateValue = rate(pmt_np, payment_mpr, -pozicka + poplatok);
    rpmn = (Math.pow(rateValue + 1, 12) - 1) * 100;
    $('[data-value="rpmn-val"]').text(price_format(rpmn));
    $('[data-value="sum"]').text(price_format(payment_mpr * mesiace + poplatok));

    $('#vyskaF').val(pozicka);
    $('#splatnostF').val(mesiace);
  if ($('input[name=poistenie]:checked').val() === '0') { $('#poistenieF').val("bez poistenia"); };
  if ($('input[name=poistenie]:checked').val() === '1') { $('#poistenieF').val("zÄ‚Ë‡kladnÄ‚Â©"); };
  if ($('input[name=poistenie]:checked').val() === '2') { $('#poistenieF').val("rozÄąË‡Ä‚Â­renÄ‚Â©"); };

  //bez benefitu repre priklad *NEW 16.11:2017 -- START
  var diffWo = (Math.round((perc) * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
  diffWo = diffWo.replace('.', ',');
  payment_mpr_full = rd(payment_mpr_full);

  var rateValue_full, rpmn_full;
  rateValue_full = rate(pmt_np, payment_mpr_full, -pozicka + poplatok);
  rpmn_full = (Math.pow(rateValue_full + 1, 12) - 1) * 100;

  $('[data-value="interest-wo"]').text(diffWo);
  $('[data-value="fee-val-wo"]').text(price_format(payment_mpr_full));
  $('[data-value="rpmn-val-wo"]').text(price_format(rpmn_full));
  $('[data-value="sum-wo"]').text(price_format(payment_mpr_full * mesiace + poplatok));
  // *NEW 16.11:2017 -- END

  }

  function rd(n) {
    var r = Math.round(n * 100) / 100;
    return r;
  }

  function price_format(number, decimals, decPoint, thousandsSep) {

    decimals = decimals || 2;
    number = parseFloat(number);

    if (!decPoint || !thousandsSep) {
      decPoint = ',';
      thousandsSep = ' ';
    }

    var roundedNumber = Math.round(Math.abs(number) * ('1e' + decimals)) + '';
    var numbersString = decimals ? roundedNumber.slice(0, decimals * -1) : roundedNumber;
    var decimalsString = decimals ? roundedNumber.slice(decimals * -1) : '';
    var formattedNumber = '';

    while (numbersString.length > 3) {
      formattedNumber += thousandsSep + numbersString.slice(-3);
      numbersString = numbersString.slice(0, -3);
    }

    return (number < 0 ? '-' : '') + numbersString + formattedNumber + (decimalsString ? (decPoint + decimalsString) : '');
  }


  //function pmt(ir, np, pv, fv = 0, type = 0) {  //defaul value nie je vsade podporovane!!! RBR
  function pmt(ir, np, pv, fv, type) {

    var fv = (typeof fv !== 'undefined') ?  fv : 0;
    var type = (typeof type !== 'undefined') ?  type : 0;

    /*
     * ir   - interest rate per month
     * np   - number of periods (months)
     * pv   - present value
     * fv   - future value
     * type - when the payments are due:
     *        0: end of the period, e.g. end of month (default)
     *        1: beginning of period
     */

    if (ir === 0) {
      return -(pv + fv) / np;
    }

    var pvif = Math.pow(1 + ir, np);
    var pmt = -ir * pv * (pvif + fv) / (pvif - 1);

    if (type === 1) {
      pmt /= (1 + ir);
    }

    return pmt;
  }

  function rate(paymentsPerYear, paymentAmount, presentValue, futureValue, dueEndOrBeginning, interest) {
    //If interest, futureValue, dueEndorBeginning was not set, set now
    if (interest == null) {
      interest = 0.01;
    }

    if (futureValue == null) {
      futureValue = 0;
    }

    if (dueEndOrBeginning == null) {
      dueEndOrBeginning = 0;

    }

    var FINANCIAL_MAX_ITERATIONS = 128; //Bet accuracy with 128
    var FINANCIAL_PRECISION = 0.0000001; //1.0e-8

    var y, y0, y1, x0, x1 = 0,
      f = 0,
      i = 0;
    var rate = interest;
    if (Math.abs(rate) < FINANCIAL_PRECISION) {
      y = presentValue * (1 + paymentsPerYear * rate) + paymentAmount * (1 + rate * dueEndOrBeginning) * paymentsPerYear + futureValue;
    } else {
      f = Math.exp(paymentsPerYear * Math.log(1 + rate));
      y = presentValue * f + paymentAmount * (1 / rate + dueEndOrBeginning) * (f - 1) + futureValue;
    }
    y0 = presentValue + paymentAmount * paymentsPerYear + futureValue;
    y1 = presentValue * f + paymentAmount * (1 / rate + dueEndOrBeginning) * (f - 1) + futureValue;

    // find root by Newton secant method
    i = x0 = 0.0;
    x1 = rate;
    while ((Math.abs(y0 - y1) > FINANCIAL_PRECISION) &&
      (i < FINANCIAL_MAX_ITERATIONS)) {
      rate = (y1 * x0 - y0 * x1) / (y1 - y0);
      x0 = x1;
      x1 = rate;

      if (Math.abs(rate) < FINANCIAL_PRECISION) {
        y = presentValue * (1 + paymentsPerYear * rate) + paymentAmount * (1 + rate * dueEndOrBeginning) * paymentsPerYear + futureValue;
      } else {
        f = Math.exp(paymentsPerYear * Math.log(1 + rate));
        y = presentValue * f + paymentAmount * (1 / rate + dueEndOrBeginning) * (f - 1) + futureValue;
      }

      y0 = y1;
      y1 = y;
      ++i;
    }
    return rate;
  }

});
```

```css
/*=================================================================*/
/*                      LOAN CALCULATOR
/*=================================================================*/
.lc-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 5px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #302f4e;
}
.lc-ranger-content {
  width: 70%;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
.lc-ranger-box {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.lc-ranger-box:first-child {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #28263e;
}
.lc-ranger-box-top {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 7px 25px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
.lc-amount {
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding-top: 20px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #FF4C60;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transform-origin: center center;
  border: 5px solid #5E5C7F;
  background: #F9F9FF;
}
.lc-amount::after {
  display: block;
  content: "EUR";
  font-size: 16px;
  letter-spacing: 0.07em;
  margin-top: -2px;
}
.lc-month {
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding-top: 20px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #FF4C60;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transform-origin: center center;
  border: 5px solid #5E5C7F;
  background: #F9F9FF;
}
.lc-month::after {
  display: block;
  content: "Mon.";
  font-size: 16px;
  letter-spacing: 0.07em;
  margin-top: -2px;
}
.lc-ranger-box-sliding {
  padding: 15px 0;
  position: relative;
}
.lc-ranger-container {
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px 0;
}

.lc-ranger-box-bottom {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 7px 25px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.lc-pyment-content {
  width: 30%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  border-left: 1px solid #28263e;
}
.lc-payment-head {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
.lc-payment-show {
  width: 100%;
}
.lc-payment {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 5px solid #5E5C7F;
  background: #F9F9FF;
  color: #FF4C60;
}
.lc-payment::after {
  display: block;
  content: "EUR/MON.";
  font-size: 16px;
  letter-spacing: 0.07em;
  margin-top: -2px;
}
.lc-payment-btn {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 4px 0 8px 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.lc-text {
  color: #F9F9FF;
}
.representative-example {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 50px 0;
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #F9F9FF;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #302f4e !important;
}
.representative-example span.span-bold {
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #FF4C60;
}
.representative-example span {
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #FF4C60;
}
#lc-range-value-bar-amount {
  width: 100%;
  content: "0";
  background-color: #FF4C60;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  height: 25px;
  top: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
#lc-range-value-bar-month {
  width: 100%;
  content: "0";
  background-color: #FF4C60;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99;
  height: 25px;
  top: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
input[type='range'] {
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border-radius: 5px
}
input[type=range]:focus {
  outline: none;
}
input[type='range'],
input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-runnable-track,
input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  animate: 0.2s;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000, 0px 0px 0px #0d0d0d;
  background: #F9F9FF;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 0px solid #000101;
}
input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.08);
  border: 14px solid #F9F9FF;
  height: 53px;
  width: 53px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  background: #FF4C60;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin-top: -13.5px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1000;
}
input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 10px; /* equal to height of runnable track */
  width: 500px; /* make this bigger than the widest range input element */
  left: -502px; /* this should be -2px - width */
  top: 8px; /* don't change this */
  background: #777;
}
input[type=range]::-moz-range-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 12.8px;
  cursor: pointer;
  animate: 0.2s;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000, 0px 0px 0px #0d0d0d;
  background: #353353;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 0px solid #000101;
}
input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000, 0px 0px 0px #0d0d0d;
  border: 0px solid #000000;
  height: 20px;
  width: 39px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  background: #000000;
  cursor: pointer;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 12.8px;
  cursor: pointer;
  animate: 0.2s;
  background: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-width: 39px 0;
  color: transparent;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-fill-lower {
  background: #000;
  border: 0px solid #000101;
  border-radius: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000, 0px 0px 0px #0d0d0d;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-fill-upper {
  background: #000;
  border: 0px solid #000101;
  border-radius: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000, 0px 0px 0px #0d0d0d;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-thumb {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000, 0px 0px 0px #0d0d0d;
  border: 0px solid #000000;
  height: 20px;
  width: 39px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  background: #000;
  cursor: pointer;
}
/*
#range-value {
  content:"0";
  background: rgba(233, 239, 244, 0.1);;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10000;
  height: 25px;
  top: -65px;
  margin: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  left: 50%;
  transform0: translateX(-50%);
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 12px;
  color: #41576B;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.08);
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
}*/
/*=================================================================*/
/*                     BUTTONS
/*=================================================================*/
.btn {
  border-radius: 30px;
  font-family: "Rubik", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 700;
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 1;
  padding: 12px 32px;
  position: relative;
}
.btn:focus {
  box-shadow: none;
}

.btn:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

@-webkit-keyframes button-push {
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
    transform: scale(0.8);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
@keyframes hvr-push {
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
    transform: scale(0.8);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
.btn-default {
  color: #FFF;
  background: #FF4C60;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
.btn-default:hover {
  color: #FFF;
  -webkit-animation-name: button-push;
  animation-name: button-push;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.3s;
  animation-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="loan bg-shadow">
        <div class="container">
            <form id="loanFormSubmit" method="get" action="{{ route('request.index') }}">
                @csrf
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="lc-wrapper shadow-main02s">
                        <div class="lc-ranger-content">
                            <div class="lc-ranger-box">
                                <div class="lc-ranger-box-top">
                                    <span class="lc-ranger-text lc-text">Choose your loan amount</span>
                                    <span id="lc-amount" class="lc-amount">6000</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="lc-ranger-box-sliding">
                                    <div class="lc-ranger-container slider-value">
                                        <input id="lc-range-amount" type="range" class="slider lc-range-slider-amount" min="500" max="6000" step="100" value="1000">
                                        <span id="lc-range-value-bar-amount"></span>
                                        <span id="lc-range-value-amount" data-value="loan" class="value" style="display:none!important;">0</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="lc-ranger-box-bottom">
                                    <span class="lc-ranger-text lc-text">500€</span>
                                    <span class="lc-ranger-text lc-text">6000€</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="lc-ranger-box">
                                <div class="lc-ranger-box-top">
                                    <span class="lc-ranger-text lc-text">Choose a maturity period</span>
                                    <span id="lc-month" class="lc-month">60</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="lc-ranger-box-sliding">
                                    <div class="lc-ranger-container slider-value">
                                        <input id="lc-range-month" type="range" class="slider lc-range-slider-month" min="6" max="60" step="1" value="24">
                                        <span id="lc-range-value-bar-month"></span>
                                        <span id="lc-range-value-month" data-value="months" class="value" style="display:none!important;">0</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="lc-ranger-box-bottom">
                                    <span class="lc-ranger-text lc-text">6 months</span>
                                    <span class="lc-ranger-text lc-text">60 months</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="lc-pyment-content">
                            <div class="lc-payment-head lc-text">
                                <h3>Your monthly payment</h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="lc-payment-show">
                                <span id="lc-payment-show" class="lc-payment value " data-value="fee">
                                    0,00
                                </span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="lc-payment-btn">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="accept-loan">
                                    I want a loan
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </section>
```

**My attempt**
added in body **onload="setData()"**
added in loan calculator form in button **onclick="submitForm()"**
and added in JS

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#accept-loan").click(function(e) {
        var loan = $("#lc-range-amount").val();
        var month = $("#lc-range-month").val();
        var pay = $("[data-value='fee']").html().replace(' ', '');
        var url = $("#loanFormSubmit")[0].setAttribute('action', '/request'+"?loan="+loan+"&months="+month+"&pay="+pay);
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            method: 'post',
            type: 'post',
            data: {
                _token: '{{csrf_token()}}',
                loan: $("#loan").html(),
                month: $("#month").html(),
                pay: $("#pay").text(),
            },
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function( data ) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
function submitForm(){
    if(typeof(localStorage) != "undefined"){
        localStorage.loan = $('[data-value="loan"]').html();
        localStorage.months = $('[data-value="months"]').html();
        localStorage.payment = $('[data-value="fee"]').html();
    }
    document.getElementById("loanFormSubmit").submit();
}

function setData(){
    if(typeof(localStorage) != "undefined"){
        document.getElementById("loan").innerHTML = localStorage.loan;
        document.getElementById("month").innerHTML = localStorage.months;
        document.getElementById("pay").innerHTML = localStorage.payment;
   }
}
```

**Everything seems to be working as I should not know whether it is right to send information like this or whether it can be done even better**

Comment: I tried too `$("#accept-loan").click(function(e) {e.preventDefault();var url = $("#loanFormSubmit").attr("action");$.ajaxSetup({headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')}});$.ajax({url: url,method: 'get',data: {lc-range-value-amount: $("#lc-range-value-amount").html(),lc-range-value-month: $("#lc-range-value-month").html(),lc-payment-show: $("#lc-payment-show").html(),}});});`

Comment: and my route `Route::get('/request', 'RequestController@index')->name('request.index');`

Comment: **but it still did nothing but a mistake** `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException
The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.`

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can receive all the data submitted in the form by using **request** method.

```
request('title') //Title is the name of the field
```

I suggest you follow this link to solve your problem. It shows all steps one by one.

https://vegibit.com/how-to-set-up-form-submission-in-laravel/

Comment: Thank you for your response....
However, I need to get data from the calculator first and transfer it to the second page where the form will be

Comment: The calculator is also storing data in a form so you can fetch the data in the similar way. kindly check

Comment: Sorry but I don't know Javascript very well ...
I have also stacked this calculator with the help of people here on the stackoverflow

Comment: no problem! you learn by doing. I will try to help you out to the best of my abilities. Answer this for me, You are passing two data fields, Load Amount and Maturnity period right?

Comment: when the client chooses the amount of the loan and the maturity will show him how much he will pay monthly it is **lc-payment-show** after clicking on button **I want a loan** it redirects to **domain.x /request** where he will see the info from previous pages where the calculator was ...

And on the **domain.xx/request** page there will be a form where you can fill in personal information and send it along with information from the calculator ....

Comment: You want the Load Amount and Maturnity period to be filled on the next page?

Comment: Yes, and also the amount of the monthly payment ...
please see above I have added the code I tried

Comment: I dont see any laravel code for the first page.

            <form id="loanFormSubmit" method="get" action="{{ route('request.index') }}">

this line has request.index, Whats in it?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your question

Comment: Show your laravel code. route('request.index') }}" here what is request.index ?

Comment: So far I only have this and I'm still trying to transfer the info from the calculator here `@extends('layouts.app')@section('content')<section class="loan bg-shadow"><div class="container"><div class="row"><div class="col-md-3">Your loan amount: <span id="loan"></span><br>Maturity period: <span id="month"></span><br>Monthly payment: <span id="pay"></span></div><div class="col-md-9"><form action="#" method="post"> {{-- Client Personal Information --}}</form></div></div></div></section>@endsection`

Comment: you mean RequestController ?

Comment: `<?phpnamespace App\Http\Controllers;use Illuminate\Http\Request;use App\Request;class RequestController extends Controller{public function store(Request $request){return view('request.index');$data = new Request;$loan = $request->input("loan");$months = $request->input("months");$pay = $request->input("pay");}}`

Comment: yes requestController complete code and the next page which it redirects to controller code as well. Edit your question above and add the code there so that it can be viewed in proper format

Comment: I don't have any more codes except the ones I added here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208802/discussion-between-mr-khan-and-syntaxeen).